# Using the Rotobrush Tool with a Graphics Tablet in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm having a lot of trouble making this work. I select rotobrush tool, I put my pen down on the graphics tablet and suddenly I'm painting instead of rotobrushing. Why is this happening? Also it happens again even when I try to use the mouse instead. The rotobrush tool is selected, yet the effect is paint.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot or two?

Comment: I can try to make a video of it instead.

Answer (score 2):

The roto-brush tool *is* a painting process - you paint green in the areas you want to rotobrush, red in the areas you don't, then tidy up edges with the feathering tool. See example here:

Comment: Not what I'm talking about here. Nice video though, but it doesn't address the problem of using a graphics tablet. The moment I do that, the tool becomes the paint tool with an empty white circle, not the rotobrush tool which is a green circle with a plus sign or red minus sign if you press alt. Rotobrush works fine with the mouse, but apparently you can't use a graphics tablet with anything but the paint or pen tool.

Comment: Ah annoying. Sorry I haven’t experienced that.